# FlexDirection Change Based on Orientation Change in React-Native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

My Code:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native'
import {
    isPortrait
} from './Constants'


export default class TwoVideoView extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.conatiner}>
                <View style={[styles.videoHalfView, {backgroundColor: 'white'}]}>
                </View>
                <View style={[styles.videoHalfView, {backgroundColor: 'gray'}]}>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    conatiner: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'red',
        flexDirection: isPortrait ? ('column') : ('row')
    },
    videoFullView: {
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
    },
    videoHalfView: {
        width: isPortrait ? ('100%') : ('50%'),
        height: isPortrait ? ('50%') : ('100%')
    }
})
```

Portrait output:

[image]

Landscape Output:
[image]

Expected Output:
[image]

Can you please help what should I do to get this done?

I tried adding Dimensions.addListener('change') didn't worked
**I just want to update My View rendering  not the other Api Stuff.**

I need to change `flexDirection: isPortrait ? ('column') : ('row')`

```
export const isPortrait = () => {
    const dim = Dimensions.get('screen');
    return dim.height >= dim.width;
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the onLayout prop to and calculate the layout based on the width and height of the container and provide the styles based on that.

I've updated the container style. You can change the rest

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  conatinerPortrait: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    flexDirection: 'column',
  },
  conatinerLandscape: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    flexDirection: 'row',
  }
});

class TwoVideoView extends React.PureComponent {
  state = {
    isPortrait: true,
  };

  calculateDimensions = ({ nativeEvent }) => {
    const { layout } = nativeEvent;

    if (layout.height > layout.width) {
      this.setState({
        isPortrait: true,
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        isPortrait: false,
      });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { isPortrait } = this.state;
    return (
      <View
        style={
          isPortrait ? styles.conatinerPortrait : styles.conatinerLandscape
        }
        onLayout={this.calculateDimensions}>
        <View
          style={[styles.videoHalfView, { backgroundColor: 'white' }]}></View>
        <View
          style={[styles.videoHalfView, { backgroundColor: 'gray' }]}></View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```